# Intellij idea - there are no line breaks in stack trace

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When executing or debugging Intellij Idea on a mac, errors in stack trace are concatenated into one line. How do I fix the line delimiter settings?

example output:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2021-09-09 06:17:55.961 ERROR 89612 ---[main] - [Trace-] o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'costOrchestrationServiceComponent' defined in file [/Users/git/mydir/build/classes/java/main/adjustment/component/CostOrchestrationServiceComponent.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appCredentialsFromVault' defined in class path resource [com.whatever.adjustment/config/PromotionAppSecretsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.whatever.adjustment.domain.AppCredentialsFromVault]: Factory method 'appCredentialsFromVault' threw exception; nested exception is com.whatever.vault.exception.VaultAccessException: [VAULT EXCEPTION] Error connecting to Vault. Could not log into Vault and retrieve auth token.u2028   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)u2028 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)u2028 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(Abstra
```

Comment: Do you set the `line.separator` property explicitly on the JVM?

Comment: That sounds like it could be the solution. Can you advise on how to set that property within Intellij?  Google has not been very helpful for that so far...

Comment: Please also include any log configuration files.

Comment: `how to set that property within Intellij?` - what run configuration do you use? There are two places you can set the property: in Run Configuration JVM Options text field or for the IDE itself using Help | Edit Custom VM Options action.